# How to fetch values from De-serialized JsonArray in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, specflow, testcase

I have a model class in **c#** as shown below:

```
public class Persons {

    public String Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public String InsuranceId {get; set;}
}
```

I am deserializing a part of **API** response in this class.

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "SteveBruns",
      "age": 24,
      "insuranceId": "M2409891"
    },
    {
      "name": "JohnStash",
      "age": 34,
      "insuranceId": "N2789012"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have to validate all the **name** and **insuranceId** fields, in my SpecFlow project. Let us say that we have a feature file as follows:

```
Feature: To hit a GET endpoint and fetch the person details

@Feature-106
Scenario: Fetch the details and validate insurance Id
Given I have a valid token
When I create a GET request for /api/insuranceDetails
Then I should validate <name1>, <name2>, <insuranceId1> and <insuranceId2> fields

Examples:
|name1      |insuranceId1 |name2     |insuranceId2|
|SteveBruns |M2409891     |JohnStash |N2789012    |
```

These are the step definitions

```
[Given(@"I have a valid token")]
public void method() {}

[When(@"I have a valid token")]
public void method() {}

[Then(@"I have a valid token")]
public void method(String name1, String insureanceId1, String name2, String insureanceId2) 
{

    // some code here
    
    var details = obj.Persons; // obj is an object of some other class where Person is residing in it
    
    // I have tried the following
    // I want to extend this for name2 and insuranceId2
    // In a nut shell, in the same testcase, I have to validate both names and insuranceId keys inside Persons JSONArray!
    
    foreach (item in details) 
    {
        item.Name.Should().Be(name1)
        item.InsuranceId.Should().Be(insuranceId1)
    }
    
    // P.S: tried this approach instead of using above foreach
    List<String> names = new List<String>();
    names.add(name1);
    names.add(name2);
    
    List<String> insuranceIds = new List<String>();
    insuranceIds.add(insuranceId1);
    insuranceIds.add(insuranceId2);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < details.size(); i++) 
    {
        String expectedName = details[i].Name;
        String expectedInsruanceId = details[i].InsuranceId;
    
        String actualName = names[i];
        String actualInsuranceId = insuranceIds[i];
    
        expectedName.Should().Be(actualName);
        expectedInsruanceId.Should().Be(actualInsuranceId );
    }

}
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Using Lambdas (select)? Any other suggestions, please help me here!

Comment: What about  name2,  insureanceId2? What are they for?

Comment: The array has two indexes of which one such index value contains Name2, insurnaceId2, in this case Name2 =JohnStash, insuranceId = N2789012. I have to check name and insturanceId from both the indices and validate against examples from feature file!

Comment: SpecFlow? Who decided to use SpecFlow?

Comment: Our client lol, we are testing our backend API services by implementing BDD via SpecFlow!

Answer (score 0):

Using a horizontal data table in your `Then` step and utilizing the [table helpers](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers.html) should do the trick. Plus, I don't see a use for an examples table (unless this is an abbreviated example of the scenario).

```
Feature: To hit a GET endpoint and fetch the person details

@Feature-106
Scenario: Fetch the details and validate insurance Id
    Given I have a valid token
    When I create a GET request for /api/insuranceDetails
    Then the insurance details should be:
        | Name       | Insurance Id |
        | SteveBruns | M2409891     |
        | JohnStash  | N2789012     |
```

And the step definition is pretty easy, assuming the column headers of the SpecFlow data table match the property names of each Person object in the JSON result:

```
[@Then(@"Then the insurance details should be:")]
public void ThenTheInsuranceDetailsShouldBe(Table table)
{
    var details = obj.Persons; // obj is an object of some other class where Person is residing in it

    // if the order of the collection does not matter
    table.CompareToSet(details);

    // if order matters
    table.CompareToSet(details, true);
}
```

Since your client wants to use Behavior-Driven Development, consider rephrasing your steps to speak their business language:

```
@Feature-106
Scenario: Fetch the details and validate insurance Id
    Given I have a valid token
    When I request the insurance details
    Then the insurance details should be:
        | Name       | Insurance Id |
        | SteveBruns | M2409891     |
        | JohnStash  | N2789012     |
```

The endpoint and the fact it is a GET request is an implementation detail that doesn't need to be communicated in a BDD scenario. Focus on the business process first.

Comment: Thank you for your brief response. Will try and let you know. I was actually looking at some SpecFlow assist helpers. Maybe this is it. And the scenario example I shared is just a sample to explain the issue, actual steps are different and coz of client restrictions, I did not add up the right steps. Back to the table, as stated I have to compare these values with the object in the model class (which has the part of API response). If there is a dynamic way to update the indexes and check the values, say name1 and name2. I used traditional for loop. Before that, the issue was with update.

Comment: To be precise, I have to compare two lists simultaneously, by validating if the array response has name1, name2 and insuranceId1, insuranceId2.

Comment: Passing `true` as the second parameter to CompareToSet(...) will also assert the order of the array is as you expect, if that helps.

Comment: I did try this, how to compare two values in same test? Because for a given scenario, if we have table with 2 rows (exclude header), it will execute with two diff sets of data right? Not sure if you have got my question but to be precise, I need to compare SteveBruns and JohnStash with the values of same which resides in ResponseObject, Simultaneously.